# select rank and count

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, subquery, where-clause

I've got a table of user profiles and I'm trying to get user's profile along with their **rank** in the system based on their exp as well as **how many users are there**. The goal for me is to eventually print that this user is say... "ranked **5th** of **135** people on the server". I can get `rank()`, but couldn't figure out how to get `max(rank())` or just a `count()` along with it, since it requires `group by`, but by grouping I'm not allowed to get meaningfull `count()`.
Here is what I tried:

```
select profile_ranked.*, max(profile_ranked.rank)
from (
    select
           *,
           rank() over (order by exp desc, id desc) as rank
    from profile
    where server_id = 6410
    ) as profile_ranked
where user_id = 1003
```

This throws error, saying gouping is required which ultimately defeats the goal.
Another thing that I tried. This time with `count()`:

```
select profile_ranked.*
from (
    select
           *,
           rank() over (order by exp desc, id desc) as rank,
           count(*) as count
    from profile
    where server_id = 6410
    group by id
    ) as profile_ranked
where user_id = 1003
```

The output in the column `count` is always 1, since I'm forced to group by id. Otherwise code doesn't even execute, throwing error.

I can do 2 queries that triverse the table twice, yes, but It doesn't make sense to do so, if all I need to do is to get result of `rank()` and `max()`. So I'm looking for a way to solve this in more of an elegant manner.
Basically, I understand that I need to append the same value of `count()` or `max()` to every row. That'd solve the issue. But I have no idea how to do that. Any help will be appretiated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a *window* count in the subquery:

```
select *
from (
    select p.*,
        rank() over (order by exp desc, id desc) as rn,
        count(*) over() as cnt
    from profile
    where server_id = 6410
) as p
where user_id = 1003
```

Comment: Yes. You're the savior. Honestly feell ashamed by such an easy solution, but it took me solid 3 hours of trying to figure it out